# How to change date format correctly? (1899-Dec-30 error)

Tags: error, calculated-column, date

I would like to use date format for "Modified" field YYYY-MM-DD instead of the default MM-DD-YYYY. So I created a calculated field with the code:

```
=TEXT(Modified,"yyyy-mmm-dd")
```

But at about 70% of the case the result is 1899-Dec-30 (That is not correct). This is based on an auto generated field so it can't be blank. Also if I modify again the value is still wrong. But if I edit and save the item without any modifications, the value is correct. The oroginal "Modified" field is always correct. I suspect the calculated field run faster than the original, so while the original's value is not calculated yet the calculated field somehow get this wrong result, but not sure. I tryed:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Modified),"",TEXT(Modified,"yyyy-mmm-dd"))
```

And looks like with this the error is not appear, but I tested only about 50 time so not sure and even if it is solved, I don't understand why. Also I never got "" result just the field started to display the correct result what is suspicious. I think with the additional calculations the calculated field runs slower than the original so it have time to get it's value, so the calculated one can get good result, but this is only a hypothesis. Do u have any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a date value never is blank, but zero.

I made it working with this:

```
=IF(Modified<1,"",TEXT(Modified,"yyyy-mmm-dd"))
```